# Raspberry pi Apache2 domain hosting

Tags: apache-httpd

Ok so i was following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzojwG7OB7c
And it seems like I've done everything.

Now I just tried to connect to the website (www.patrick-gruszka.com) on my LTE connection to check if it is working, but it just says server unavailable. Any ideas? 
Im also using google domains for my domain. Sorry if I do not have enough info, just don't know what to ask.

Comment: Is your LTE provider allow port 80 (http)?

Answer (score 1):

The net address for www.patrick-gruszka.com only resolves to an IPv6 of 2601:243:1801:a4f0::3.  There is no IPv4 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx type) address. Unless you have IPv6 connectivity, you won't be able to reach your Pi server.

Can you 'ping' your Pi server?  [ ' ping 2601:243:1801:a4f0::3 ' ]

Can you update google dns with your IPv4 address?

Have you opened the necessary port(s) on your router/modem?

Comment: Since any of the above could be the cause of the problem it is fine as an answer.